# Как реализовать схему аутентификации пользователя в приложении Vk Mini Apps на стороне сервера?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Необходимо при чтении запроса от приложения в вк проверить то, что запрос отправлен с определенного профиля.

При отправке первого запроса приложение посылает в url подпись (sign), что очень удобно и позволяет отличить оригинальный запрос от фейкового (подставного, перехваченного и измененного).

Как сделать нечто подобное при каждом запросе? Не хочется писать костыли и парсить HTML для получения подписи из url в атрибуте src фрейма с приложением, чтобы достать отправленный при первом запросе sign.

В идеале сделать подобный ключ уникальным для каждого запроса, но можно и одним ключом из первого обойтись для начала.

Пока все шлю через XMLHttpRequest. Его вк никак не преобразует. Библиотеки вк по документации уже второй день читаю, никак не могу найти чего-то встроенного. Допускаю, что смотрю не туда.

## UPD2. Проблема решена.

Comment: Я немного не понял вопрос. Но знаю, что при использовании `Callback API`, ВК может каждый раз передавать секретный ключ, чтобы гарантировать подлинность данных. Может, это поможет Вам.

Comment: Используйте токены

Comment: В авторизации через vk-api есть все необходимые методы для ответа на ваш вопрос. При успешной авторизации вам выдается токен пользователя и запрашиваемая информация о нем. В апи есть методы для валидации токена, вы можете использовать их. Пока-что не понятна суть вашей проблемы, т.к. вы не знаете элементарных вещей в документации и не можете сформулировать вопрос должным образом. Я понял что вам нужно, сделать доступ к функциям по id и по подписи. Вам опять же, не нужно ничего самому придумывать, всё есть в документации.

Comment: Да, несколько неочевидный, но ответ и правда в документации.

Answer (score 2):

Коротко схема решения.

После инициализации приложения посылаем запрос на **получение access_token для вошедшего пользователя**.

```
connect.send("VKWebAppGetAuthToken", {"app_id": 7105020, "scope": "friends"});
```

Полученный в ответе access_token отправляем на запросы сервера до тех пор, пока не истечет expire (по умолчанию вроде час).

**Проверка на сервере**

Предварительно **получаем access_token для приложения** по адресу

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<secure_key>&grant_type=client_credentials&v=5.101
```

В ответ приходит JSON с access_token, он нужен на следующем шаге.

**Проверка access_token пользователя по адресу**

```
https://api.vk.com/method/secure.checkToken?client_secret=<secure_key>&token=<access_token пользователя>&access_token=<access_token приложения>&v=5.101
```

В ответ приходит user_id, дата начала (date) и дата завершения (expire) действия ключа.

В общем, если делать так, то просто в качестве одного из ключей в URL или параметра в body запроса можно передавать access_token из приложения  и проверять его на стороне сервера. Я пользуюсь все тем же XMLHttpRequest.

Ответ взят с:
https://vk.com/dev/secure.checkToken
https://vk.com/dev/secure.sendNotification

И да здравствует интернет, который знает про доп.ключи в этих запросах.

Answer (score 0):

Официальный [вариант от VK](https://github.com/tsivarev/vk-direct-games-example):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) === variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
    return null;
}

function submitScore(score) {
    var url = 'https://...';
    var params = {
        'score': score,
        'viewer_id': getQueryVariable('viewer_id'),
        'api_id': getQueryVariable('api_id'),
        'auth_key': getQueryVariable('auth_key')
    };

    ...
}
```

Так что предложенный в самом вопросе способ, вполне можно использовать.